# Can I see a list of all Temporary Variables?

Tags: ms-access, vba

Is it possible in Microsoft Access to return a list of all of my temporary variables, or all temporary variables that contain a non-Null value?

This functionality would be useful when I don't remember the exact name of temp variable, or when I want to purge old/forgotten ones that are no longer necessary.

I've tried using Intellisense. Although it will auto-complete "TempVars," it doesn't list the specific variable names.

If there is not a clean way to do list the temporary variables in a database, I'd be interested to know how other Access developers manage their temporary variables, especially when there is a large number of them.

Comment: As a side note, IMHO most Access developers don't use TempVars, because their main use is for macros, which most devs don't use (besides Autoexec).

Comment: I also use them in VBA and queries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can loop through the `TempVars` collection and examine the `Name` and `Value` of each ...

```vb
Dim tv As TempVar
Debug.Print "TempVars.Count: " & TempVars.Count
For Each tv In TempVars
    Debug.Print tv.name, tv.Value
Next
```

If you want only non-Null `TemVars` ...

```vb
For Each tv In TempVars
    If Not IsNull(tv.Value) Then
        Debug.Print tv.name, tv.Value
    End If
Next
```